# Setting address of whois service for ruby whois gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, whois, whois-ruby

Using the ruby whois gem, how do I set the server address of the whois service?

Setting the bind_host, I get an error.

```
> whois_client = Whois::Client.new(bind_host: "192.0.47.59", bind_port: 43)
=> #<Whois::Client:0x00000008188e7e50 @timeout=10, @settings={:bind_host=>"192.0.47.59", :bind_port=>43}>
> record = whois_client.lookup('wandajackson.com')
Whois::ConnectionError: Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Can't assign requested address - bind(2) for "192.0.47.59" port 43
    from (irb):4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `bind_host` doesn't refer to the host used for the whois lookup, but instead [refers to the adapter binding on the server running your code](https://github.com/weppos/whois/blob/7e27854a6e2730e5bab22eb26bed54f075337b8e/lib/whois/client.rb#L36-L38). By default [it binds to 0.0.0.0](https://github.com/weppos/whois/blob/7e27854a6e2730e5bab22eb26bed54f075337b8e/lib/whois/server/adapters/base.rb#L33), or all the adapters on the local server.

If you want to have the whois gem use a custom server address for looking up whois information then it appears that you have to specify it in one of the following ways:

```
# Define a server for the .com TLD
Whois::Server.define :tld, "com", "your.whois.server.address"
Whois.whois("google.com")

# Define a new server for an range of IPv4 addresses
Whois::Server.define :ipv4, "10.0.0.0/8", "your.whois.server.address"
Whois.whois("10.0.0.1")

# Define a new server for an range of IPv6 addresses
Whois::Server.define :ipv6, "2001:2000::/19", "your.whois.server.address"
Whois.whois("2001:2000:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334")
```

These examples were taken from https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/whois/Whois/Server.

Comment: Worked for ".com", but not for IP addresses.