# Setting address of whois service for ruby whois gem for IP addresses

Tags: ruby, rubygems, whois, whois-ruby

A Connection to whois.arin.net is not open to us. Our network administrators say we should use 192.0.47.59 for our whois service.

In some cases I will have a DNS name, in other cases I will have an IP address. I want to get the whois information in either case. My network administrators have allowed access to a specific IP address for the whois service, and I have to use that IP address. The define method allows me to set the IP address of the whois service if I give it the TLD, but I have no way to get it work for IP addresses.

This is related to [Setting address of whois service for ruby whois gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52431103/setting-address-of-whois-service-for-ruby-whois-gem), but since I got a partial solution, I know how to call the service, so for my question specific to IP addresses I thought I would start over.

I need to set the address of our whois service.  So for a DNS name:

```
> Whois.whois('wandajackson.com')
Whois::ConnectionError: Errno::EHOSTUNREACH: No route to host - connect(2) for "whois.verisign-grs.com" port 43
    from (irb):4
> Whois::Server.define(:tld, 'com', '192.0.47.59')
=> ["com", "192.0.47.59", {}]
irb(main):006:0> Whois.whois('wandajackson.com')
# => #<Whois::Record>
```

However, I cannot get it to work for IP addresses.

```
> Whois::Server.define(:ipv4, '74.0.0.0/8', '192.0.47.59')
=> ["74.0.0.0/8", "192.0.47.59", {}]
> Whois.whois('74.220.215.203')
Whois::ConnectionError: Errno::EHOSTUNREACH: No route to host - connect(2) for "whois.arin.net" port 43
    from (irb):7

> Whois::Server.define(:ipv6, '2607::/8', '192.0.47.59')
=> ["2607::/8", "192.0.47.59", {}]
> Whois.whois('2607:f8b0:4004:800::200e')
Whois::ConnectionError: Errno::EHOSTUNREACH: No route to host - connect(2) for "whois.arin.net" port 43
    from (irb):9
```

Comment: I think you got it mixed up.  It you setup a record for whois you are matching the domain `wandajackson.com` (:tld com) to an IP address.  You ask with an IP address you get record from whois; you ask with a domain name you get the record from whois.  Why are you trying to do a pair with IP/IP?

Comment: In some cases I will have a DNS name, in other cases I will have an IP address.  I want to get the whois information in either case.  My network administrators have allowed access to a specific IP address for the whois service, and I have to use that IP address.  The define method allows me to set the IP address of the whois service if I give it the TLD, but I have no way to get it work for IP addresses.

Comment: I see that makes sense.  I got curious and tested your code for the ip4 and it worked correctly (got a reply).  Could you test your connection for `whois.arin.net` on port `43` via e.g. telnet?  Why is your first query asking `whois.verisign-grs.com` and the second whois.arin.net?  (I got -Whois::Server.define(:ipv4, '74.0.0.0/8', '192.0.47.59')
 => ["74.0.0.0/8", "192.0.47.59", {}] 
2.5.1 :003 > Whois.whois('74.220.215.203')
 => "\n#\n# ARIN WHOIS data and services are ...

Comment: Connection to `whois.arin.net` is not open to us.  Our network administrators say we should use `192.0.47.59` for our whois service.

Comment: I see.  Now I understand your problem! I'll check it out.

Comment: I more detail - I would recommend using name `whois.iana.org` instead of 192.0.47.95.  The chances that IANA changes IP address is rather small, but it increases readability & also should IANA change address it will still work (when IT changes the firewall rules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to say but that is a bug with missing `74.0.0.0/8` assigment & if you create your own it is probably not correctly searched for in the `defined` list thus =>  The assigment according to IP does not  currently work.

### Why?

You can check the list and find out which ranges are assigned to ARIN:

```
Whois::Server.definitions(:ipv4).each { |records| p "IP range #{records[0]}" if records[1] = 'whois.arin.net'}
```

First without any changes you check your IP address:

```
 Whois::Server.find_for_ip("74.220.215.203")
=> #<Whois::Server::Adapters::Arin:0x00000000030244c0 @type=:ipv4, @allocation="0.0.0.0/1", @host="whois.arin.net", @options={}>
```

As you can see the record is not found at the authorities so it goes to a fallback `0.0.0.0/1` which is set for `whois.arin.net`.

I tried to set `fatory` (gets somehow ignored) and `define`:

```
Whois::Server.factory :ipv4, "74.0.0.0/8", "whois.iana.org", :option => Whois::Server::Adapters::Standard
```

`define` worked:

```
Whois::Server.define :ipv4, "74.0.0.0/8", "whois.iana.org"
```

> ... , {}], ["222.120.0.0/15", "whois.nic.or.kr", {}], ["222.122.0.0/16",
>   "whois.nic.or.kr", {}], ["222.232.0.0/13", "whois.nic.or.kr", {}],
>   ["220.0.0.0/6", "whois.apnic.net", {}], ["74.0.0.0/8",
>   "whois.iana.org", {}]]

As you can see there is assigment of

```
["74.0.0.0/8",
> "whois.iana.org", {}]]
```

so you should be able to query IANA now?  It appears you are not:

```
Whois::Server.find_for_ip("74.220.215.203")
=> #<Whois::Server::Adapters::Arin:0x000000000434c250 @type=:ipv4, @allocation="0.0.0.0/1", @host="whois.arin.net", @options={}>
```

As you can see the `@allocation` is still getting `"0.0.0.0/1"` and not `74.0.0.0/8`.  Why? That I don't know yet.  Probably some bug either on searching or finding the correct Object.

Everything is lost?  Not really, there is rather simple workaround but you have to understand the implications.

### Workaround

If you define your fallback address via:

```
Whois::Server.define :ipv4, "0.0.0.0/1", "whois.iana.org"
```

Everything starts to work.  Now all the fallback queries will be done via IANA, which should not be a problem in your case as you can't reach ARIN anyways.

Now if you query via IP adddress you get correct results:

```
Whois::Server.find_for_ip("74.220.215.203")
=> #<Whois::Server::Adapters::Standard:0x000000000351c298 @type=:ipv4, @allocation="0.0.0.0/1", @host="whois.iana.org", @options={}>

Whois.whois("74.220.215.203")
=> "% IANA WHOIS server\n% for more information on IANA, visit http://www.iana.org\n% This query returned 1 object\n\nrefer:        whois.arin.net\n\ninetnum:
    74.0.0.0 - 74.255.255.255\norganisation: ARIN\nstatus:       ALLOCATED\n\nwhois:        whois.arin.net\n\nchanged:      2005-06\nsource:       IANA\n\n"
```